# Почему TgBot присылает "document"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Необходимо реализовать задачу, чтобы бот при отправке ему текста "file" присылал файл с ssh сервера.

Тут вызываю библиотеки, которые необходимы будут:

```
import paramiko
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
```

Затем делаю коннект к самому серверу SSH

```
host = "host"
port = 22
bot = Bot(token = 'YOUR_TOKEN')
mybot = Dispatcher(bot)

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD')
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Затем вызываю команду */start*

```
@mybot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    station = InlineKeyboardButton(text='file', callback_data='file')
    markup.add(station)
    await message.reply('Выберите просмотр', reply_markup=markup)
```

Далее уже функцию, которая будет реализовывать отправку файла при нажатии на кнопку **"file"**

```
@mybot.callback_query_handler(text='file')
async def menu_index(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    a = '/usr/tgbotTok/files/123.pdf'
    await call.message.answer_document(document=sftp.open(a, 'rb').read())
```

Ну и соответственно *Executor*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  executor.start_polling(mybot)
```

Это весь код в моем боте, однако
[image: на выходе я получаю не файл с расширением .pdf, а только "document" в ответе телеграм бота]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как следует изменить код или может другую библиотеку просто попробовать использовать для этой задачи?

Comment: Ну по логике это и есть тот файл, который бот должен был отправить. Если смущает что имя файла не соответствует тому что вы отправляете, то оборачивайте в объект InputFile, через параметр там указывайте имя файла: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/input_file.html

Comment: @insolor да, все так, это тот файл, но открыть его с телефона, так как отсутствует расширение файла. А необходимо, чтобы было название и его расширение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
import io

from aiogram.types import InputFile

@mybot.callback_query_handler(text='file')
async def menu_index(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    a = '/usr/tgbotTok/files/123.pdf'
    file = InputFile(io.BytesIO(sftp.open(a, 'rb').read()), filename="1234.pdf")
    await call.message.answer_document(document=file)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка "TypeError: Not supported file type.". 
Вы попробовали файл с сервера грузить или с компа? Просто я пытаюсь именно с сервера файл забрать и отправить в телеграм

Comment: @anywayaleksey попробуйте теперь, добавил `io.BytesIO` не знаю сработает ли

Comment: Супер. Работает!!!
Огромнейшей респект :)